# Pandas replace invalid datetime values with values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataset in which, for some reason, some of the `datetimes` show up as random `int`s:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_show = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ['11/05/2020', '12/02/2020', '12/02/2020'],
    "time": ['19:14:28', '19:14:28', '19:16:28'],
    "datetime": [np.datetime64('2020-11-05T19:14:28.000000000'), np.datetime64('2020-12-02T19:14:28.000000000'), 12]
})
```

My goal is to specifically replace those values with a `datetime` value by combining the `date` and `time` cols. I have two approaches, but both fail.

1. Find the specific values based on the cell `type` and replaces them with concatenated and converted to datetime type:

```py
df_show.loc[pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce').isnull(), ["datetime"]] = pd.to_datetime(
df_show.loc[pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce').isnull()]["date"].astype(str) + ' ' \
' '+df_show.loc[pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce').isnull()]["time"].astype(str)
    )
```

However, this returns an `int` again, which corresponds to the datetime but is `int`. Why is it happening? Why don't I get the normal `datetime[ns]` type? And how can I convert it into `datetime`? Doing

```
 pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce')
```

doesn't work since it converts the `int` into `NaT`.

---

2. First convert the col into `datetime`, then replace the `NaT`.

```py
df_show['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce')
df_show.loc[df_show['datetime'].isnull(), ["datetime"]] = pd.to_datetime(
df_show.loc[df_show['datetime'].isnull()]["date"].astype(str) + ' ' \
' '+df_show.loc[df_show['datetime'].isnull()]["time"].astype(str)
    )
```

for which I'm getting:

```py
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]
```

and I don't understand why. Both sides have the same type `datetime64[ns]` so why this error message? And how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is the right direction. To fix it, use `.loc[rows, col]` instead of `.loc[rows, [col]]`:

```
# you want to reuse this
invalid_dates = df_show['datetime'].isnull()

df_show.loc[invalid_dates, "datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_show.loc[invalid_dates, "date"].astype(str) + ' ' \
    + df_show.loc[invalid_dates, "time"].astype(str)
    )
```

However, you can just use `fillna`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df_show[['date','time']].agg(' '.join, axis=1))
df_show['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_show['datetime'], errors='coerce').fillna(s)
```

Comment: wait, what? :D It's a copy paste error which I made with the `.loc[rows, [col]]` in my code (your sol works) but now I got also confused. I thought those are equivalent if you have one element only. Could you please explain why it behaves differently? Thanks

Comment: They are not. One gives a dataframe, the other gives a series. So in your original code, you are trying to update a one-column dataframe with a series, and idk what Pandas is doing in the background in that case so as it fails.